# npm install irc failing

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been trying to install the node-irc library for Node.Js.

I seem to be running into this issue and not sure why. I installed a fresh copy of Node.JS (version 4.22), I have .NET Framework 2.0 SDK installed on Windows, and Python 2.7.10

Here is the error:

> C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Test\node_modules\irc\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
>
> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,please add the "/m" switch.
>
> d:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h':No such file or directory
>
> [C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Test\node_modules\irc\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector\build\binding.sln]
>
> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error:
>
> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
>
> gyp ERR! command "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Program Files(x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Test\node_modules\irc\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> iconv@2.1.11 install C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Test\node_modules\irc\node_modules\
>   iconv
>   node-gyp rebuild